# What is the difference between Ad_group_ad and Ad_group tables?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I was asked to call Google-Ads API in order to create a report with these fields:
[image]

I went to `ad_group_ad` table.

I wanted to make sure I understand this table's meaning:
Why isn't this just called Ad?

What is the difference between `Ad_group_ad` and `Ad_group` tables?

There were a few metrics which I couldn't find in `ad_group_ad`
I couldn't filter the views which contain them (for example `impression_share`)

[image]

I know `impression_share` exists for `keywords` and `campaign`, so I found them in the relevant tables. So I understand they cannot be broken down at an ad level.

But I still couldn't find the other highlighted metrics even at a campaign level.

[image]

Here is my campaign query try:

```
SELECT 
  metrics.clicks, 
  metrics.impressions, 
  metrics.ctr, 
  metrics.cost_micros, 
  metrics.cost_per_conversion, 
  metrics.cost_per_all_conversions, 
  metrics.all_conversions_from_interactions_rate, 
  metrics.all_conversions_value, 
  campaign.name, 
  campaign.id, 
  segments.device, 
  segments.date, 
  campaign.advertising_channel_type, 
  segments.click_type, 
  campaign.geo_target_type_setting.positive_geo_target_type, 
  campaign.geo_target_type_setting.negative_geo_target_type 
FROM campaign 
WHERE 
  segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2022-01-01' 
ORDER BY 
  campaign.start_date DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The [AdGroupAd (ad_group_ad)](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/AdGroupAd) is the Google Ads API representation of the actual Ad inside a specific Campaign's [Ad Group (ad_group)](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/AdGroup) object. The AdGroupAd has a sub-object called Ad which holds additional property to only go deeper into the specific Ad types like RSA, Call Ad, Expanded Text (for a few more weeks), etc.

I find it helpful to traverse the Google API Docs starting with the AdGroupAd and work your way down to the Ad and specific Ad Types to see the hierarchy.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/AdGroupAd

From a reporting standpoint, via the API you will be able to see the specific AdGroup any given AdGroupAd is attached to so and then you can then get to the actual Campaign by either ID or Resource Name.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/AdGroup